# Android Firebase - Getting null value in addChildEvevntListener after adding data to firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am having two classes one is for uploading data, and other one is for retrieving data using addChildEventListener in firebase. My problem is when i upload the data its getting stored in database correctly. but as soon as i upload my data my childEventListener throwing null value. But when i manually add data to firebase database (website) am getting correctly.

Here is my uploading class

```
   Firebase mref = new Firebase("https://social-a92cf.firebaseio.com/user");

 Firebase create;
       //name
       create = mref.child(user+"_" + key_id).child("firstname");
       create.setValue(profile_Name);

       //date
       create = mref.child(user+"_" + key_id).child("date");
       create.setValue(date);

       //place
       create = mref.child(user+"_" + key_id).child("place");
       create.setValue(place);

      //description
        create=mref.child(user+"_"+key_id).child("description");
        create.setValue(description);

        //imageurl
       create = mref.child(user+"_" + key_id).child("url");
       create.setValue(IMG_URL);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My addChildEventListener

```
mref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            if(flag==1) {

                ContactInfo ci = new ContactInfo();

                if(dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue()!=null && dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue()!=null && dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue()!=null && dataSnapshot.child("place").getValue()!=null && dataSnapshot.child("date").getValue()!=null) {


                    ci.displayName = dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue().toString();
                    ci.displayDate = dataSnapshot.child("date").getValue().toString();
                    ci.description = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue().toString();
                    ci.displayPlace = dataSnapshot.child("place").getValue().toString();
                    ci.imgUrl = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue().toString();
                    list.add(ci);
                    ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    recList.smoothScrollToPosition(ca.getItemCount());

                }
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Problem in loading feeds",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    });
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue please.

Comment: Again when i restart my application am getting that data correctly.

Comment: You still have an NPE. When you get it doesn't matter, you probably make a call to early which means it returns null. An NPE is an NPE

Comment: @LunarWatcher can you help to solve this issue please.